# Flexbox 100% height with scrollable div inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i want to have a flexbox who size the complete browser window / device.
And inside i want content with scrollable div's.

i don't know why the Content Area fly's over the Footer div and why the two Content-Divs are not scrollable in the right way.

I colored all the div's for a better view. I try 100vh on height too but unsuccessfully.
I just want a fixed (100%) height and width for the wrapper div.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    background-color:aqua;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:50px;
}
.header01 {
  flex:0 0 49px; /*grow shrink basis*/
  background-color: white;
}
.header02 {
  flex:0 1 214px;
  background-color: red;
}
.header03 {
  flex:1;
  background-color: green;
}
.header04 {
  flex:0 1 245px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.header05 {
  flex:0 1 147px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navcon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: row;
  height:100%;
}
.nav {
  flex:0 0 250px; /*grow shrink basis*/
  background-color: green;
}
.con {
    flex:1; /*grow shrink basis*/
  background-color:brown;
}
.maincon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color:white;
}
.con {
  background-color:blueviolet;
  flex:1;
}
.innercon{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.nav_ext{
    flex:0 0 50px;
    background-color:bisque;
}
.content1{
    flex:0 0 247px;
    background-color:burlywood;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
.content2{
    flex:0 1 247px;
    background-color:chocolate;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
.content3{
    flex:1;
    background-color:crimson;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
.content4{
    flex:0 0 50px;
    background-color:darkgoldenrod;
}
.footer {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color:darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="header01">H1</div>
        <div class="header02">H2</div>
        <div class="header03">H3</div> 
        <div class="header04">H4</div> 
        <div class="header05">H5</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="navcon">
        <div class="nav">Nav</div>
        <div class="con">
            <div class="maincon">
                <div class="header">Header</div>
                <div class="con">
                    <div class="innercon">
                        <div class="nav_ext">NavExt</div>
                        <div class="content1">C1</div>
                        <div class="content2">C2<br/><br/>test<br/>1231123123132<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>test2<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>test3</div>
                        <div class="content3">C3</div>
                        <div class="content4">C4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
Here you can see a little Visual Demonstration what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbEni.jpg
The Browser windows is filled with that, and can **just** scroll inside the div's, I've "painted" some scrollbars to visualize.

Comment: Try `max-height: 100vh`

Comment: Grid will be more suitable in this case

Comment: How would a grid be more suitable? A grid not will do anythign that the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hight of 100%. Then give the wrapper the css attribute: `position: absolute;` and combine it with `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` that way the div will will the entire screen height and width. To have the content scrollable when overflowing, add: `overflow-y: auto;`

```css
html, body{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:aqua;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:50px;
}
.header01 {
  flex:0 0 49px; /*grow shrink basis*/
  background-color: white;
}
.header02 {
  flex:0 1 214px;
  background-color: red;
}
.header03 {
  flex:1;
  background-color: green;
}
.header04 {
  flex:0 1 245px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.header05 {
  flex:0 1 147px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="header01">H1</div>
        <div class="header02">H2</div>
        <div class="header03">H3</div> 
        <div class="header04">H4</div> 
        <div class="header05">H5</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="navcon">
        <div class="nav">Nav</div>
        <div class="con">
            <div class="maincon">
                <div class="header">Header</div>
                <div class="con">
                    <div class="innercon">
                        <div class="nav_ext">NavExt</div>
                        <div class="content1">C1</div>
                        <div class="content2">C2<br/><br/>test<br/>1231123123132<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>test2<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>test3</div>
                        <div class="content3">C3</div>
                        <div class="content4">C4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try that, the content doesn't overflow anymore, that's great, thank you. But the overall wrapper is higher than the browser window, so scrollbars appear on the side, i want to avoid that, how can I do that?

Comment: remove overflow from the wrapper. However without any kind of overflow, the content will be cut when the contents height is higher then the wrappers height.

Comment: my wrapper has:
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:aqua;
  
}
but it didnt work, it is because of the "content1,2,3..." css?

Comment: proberly. btw, you should not use `overflow: hidden;` in any normal case. it does not only hide the scrollbar but also disabel the scroll ability while not preventing overflow. And make an image of the design you want to sue. That way it easier to see how we could fix that

Comment: I've added and image for visualization.